# Redux update object with multiple params

Tags: javascript, redux

Hello i have my reducers like this

```
case UPDATE_USER: {
  return {
    ...state,
    ...action.newDataUser,
  }
}
```

My object user is :

```
 {
    name: 'azerty',
    email: 'azerty@yopmail.com',
    birthday: '1990'
 }
```

I have an action to update my user object :

```
export function updateUser(newDataUser) {
  return { type: UPDATE_USER, newDataUser }
}
```

How to modify my reducers UPDATE_USER to update user object with multiple properties :

```
{
   name: 'azerty updated',
   email: 'azerty@yopmail.com updated',
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: so does the answer below work for you?

Answer (score -1):

You can manually update required properties

```
case UPDATE_USER: {
  let user = action.newDataUser;
  ['name', 'email', 'birthday'].forEach(key => {
     user[key] = `${user[key]} updated`;
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    ...user,
  }
}
```